# Fore apply new element as default element for directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to force setup new element as default element from directive? With attention new element must be connected to this scope.

example:

```
<div ng-test />
```

JS:

```
app.directive("ngTest", ["$interval", "$compile", function($interval, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                if($element[0].tagName === "div"){
                    var el = document.createElement('span');
                    el.setAttribute('ngTest','')
                    $element[0].outerHTML = el.outerHTML;
                }
                console.log($element[0]) // still <div>, but from domDocument has been changed to span
                // how to force apply? 
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: why do you want to change it to span? you're not changing the tagName, only the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe all you need to do is to set inline style for the div with directive `ngTest`?

```
div[ng-test] {
    display: inline;
}
```

But if you really have a good reason to replace `div` with `span`, you can do it this way:

```
var el = angular.element(document.createElement('span'));
el.attr('ng-test', '').html($element.html());

$element.replaceWith(el);
$compile(el)($scope);
$element = el;
```

Note, that you can't just replace `outerHTML`. You need to set inner content properly, set attribute (it's `ng-test`, not `ngTest`), replace old div with new span and compile it.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/EsU7Ke4nMlPiQXZ7VWXc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a template for a directive and there is the replace-flag, which removes the old directive-element and inserts the template as `$element[0]`.

```
return {
      replace: true,
      template: '<span></span>',
      restrict: 'A',
      //...
};
```

Comment: I'm not using template like that, but I'm getting any xml by XHR/AJAX to replace old element.